# vue / nodejs & nginx in docker: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops

directory structure:

```
myapp
-- frontend
---- docker
------ frontend
-------- nginx
-------- nginx.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/THxMf0xM
(moved to pastebin to avoid that annoying "mostly code" error)

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vue:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

why do I get `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` ?

Comment: this error occurs when your service is not running inside the container, check for service logs , in this case nginx

Comment: the vue service runs well. i can access the vue service in the browser. however when I access the nginx service in the browser, the error shows up

Comment: okay, another thing to check could be if port mappings are in place is vue running at 8081 and are you hitting browser as http i.e. on port 80 ?

Comment: as I said, the vue app runs well on localhost:8081. but the nginx somehow can't serve the vue app to a given port based on DOCKER_FRONTEND_PORT variable, in this case.I gave the variable with 3300

Comment: looking at your code , i could see you are mapping 8081 to 8080 , shouldn't that be 80 as nginx is listening on port 80 ?

Comment: vue cli has default port of 8080. I mapped it to 8081 cause turns out 8080 is used on the host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by changing `proxy_pass http://vue:8081;` to `proxy_pass http://vue:8080;`

notice the 8080 port.

secondly, rebuild the frontend service

and lastly, remove the `ports` option from vue service

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

`https://pastebin.com/THxMf0xM`  line number 23, should be pointing to port 80 i.e. `ports: - '8081:80'`

Comment: would you elaborate why I should map it to 80 instead of 8080? vue cli serves their app on 8080 by default

Comment: to match mapping of frontend with backend, which you did other way around in your answer below